# SQl to DataTable with isolationlevel.Readuncommitted

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I have the code below and i'm wanting to make sure it does what I think it does.

Simply i'm trying to fill a datatable with a select command, and I want to use isolationlevel.readuncommitted with whatever command I use.

```
DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
TransactionOptions transOptions = new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted };
using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transOptions))
{

    SqlCommand sqlCMD = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, SqlCon);
    sqlCMD.CommandTimeout = 0;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCMD);
    sqlDataAdp.Fill(dtTable);
}
return dtTable;
```

Comment: Is there a question with that? can you clarify what does/doesn't work?

Comment: You may consider just using the NOWAIT command in your SELECT statement.  It would be an alternative that would be less complicated. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx